# How to build a custom slider in Flash AS3?

Tags: javascript, actionscript-3, flash

I am in need of some help making custom sliders, sort of like the ones you would use for volume buttons. I have one but it's not multi usable; as soon as I add more than one the ones before stop working, and I don't think I can use local variables because I need to use event listeners for the scrubber to slide.

All I am asking is if someone can please put a code for a multi usable slider with explanation on how it works so I can learn from it. I can show the code I am using right now but its probably useless.

```
public function createSlider(x:Number, y:Number, parent:DisplayObjectContainer) : void {
        this.slider = new Sprite();
        this.slider.graphics.beginFill(0xFFFFFF);
        this.slider.graphics.drawCircle(x, y, 7);
        this.slider.graphics.endFill();
        this.bar = makeRoundedRect(x - 6, y - 6, 100, 11, 0xCCCCCC, 1, [10, 10, 10, 10]);
        parent.addChild(bar);
        parent.addChild(slider);

        this.slider.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OVER, sliderHover);
    }

    private function sliderHover(e:MouseEvent) : void 
    {
        this.slider.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, sliderDown);
    }
    private function sliderDown(e:MouseEvent) : void {
        this.slider.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_MOVE, sliderMove);
        this.slider.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, sliderDone);
        this.slider.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OUT, sliderDone);
    }

    private function sliderMove(e:MouseEvent) : void {
        this.slider.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, sliderDown);
        this.slider.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_MOVE, sliderMove);
        this.slider.startDrag(false, new Rectangle(0, slider.y, 90, 0));

    }
    private function sliderDone(e:MouseEvent) : void {
        this.temp_mouseCurX = Math.abs(this.slider.x + 10);
        trace(this.temp_mouseCurX);
        this.slider.stopDrag();
    }
```

It's using a private variable which I know shouldn't be good for what I am trying to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should try using e.currentTarget. instead of this.slider.

Comment: I Will look into this, i havnt used that code before thank you for bringing it up i will test in a bit

Comment: Great. "e" is the mouse event. It contains all kinds of great info about your click such as different kinds of positions and the current target of you click action! Using "this." is very rarely needed in actionscript 3.

Comment: Yea i see the knowledge behind how its working now, Its using the name i gave the mouse event could be 'evt' , 'e' its just referring to the object using the mouse event at that time right? instead of referring to the actual variable itself

Comment: Yes, its like if you create a normal function and passes a varible as a parameter to it, the name of the original variable doesnt matter in the new scope, we can store it in whatever local variable we want to.